# mysql error "cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-error-1064

Here is the mysql query:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_juices_members
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_juiceid FOREIGN KEY(juice_id) REFERENCES wp_juices(id)
```

All the tables, fields exist with the correct names as specified in the above query, and i still get this error:

"cannot add foreign key constraint"

Here are the DESC for the two tables:

wp_juices_members:

```
Field       Type    Null    Key Default Extra   
id          int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
member_id   int(11) YES     NULL    
juice_id    int(11)
```

wp_juices:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra   
id  int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
name    varchar(255)    NO      NULL
```

UPDATE:  Actually I figured it out, the fields being matched have to be same type, and adjectives like unsigned or not not null etc.  Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: mysql won't create an FK that would leave the member tables in an inconsistent state. So you've either got an error in the FK definition (e.g. field type/size mismatch), or you've got orphaned records that need to be cleaned up.

Comment: ^^ The data type and size of `juice_id` must exactly match that of `wp_juices.id`.

Comment: so basically your saying there are inconsistencies with table names, field names, and/or types of the field names?

Comment: names don't matter, types do. Also, both tables must support foreign keys (i.e. you can't reference a MyISAM table).

Comment: @dave Post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for both of the involved tables, and it will usually be easy to spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add a description of the table you are using just `DESC table_name` then update your question.

the most common reason will be that the number of `digit` in each of your column you want to link with a reference is different maybe `INT(11) UNSIGNED` and `INT(11) SIGNED` will create a big difference.